# Nextjs navbar active class only becomes active on a second click

Tags: reactjs, next.js, navbar

I'm trying to create header component for next.js/tailwindcss app. The nav active class only shows active when clicked on a second time. I'd like for it to be active upon the first click. Where am I going wrong? What element should I target with tailwindcss to reflect active state?

navlink.js file:

```
    import Link from 'next/link';

const NavItem = ({ text, href, active }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <a
        className={`nav__item ${
          active ? 'active underline underline-offset-8' : ''
        }`}
      >
        {text}
      </a>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NavItem;
```

header.js :

```
    import Image from 'next/image';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import NavItem from './NavItem';
const MENU_LIST = [
  { text: 'About', href: '/about' },
  { text: 'My Work', href: '/MyWork' },
  { text: 'Blog', href: '/blog' },
  { text: 'Contact', href: '/contact' },
];
const Header = () => {
  const [navActive, setNavActive] = useState(null);
  const [activeIdx, setActiveIdx] = useState(-1);

  return (
    <header className="bg-white">
      <nav className="max-w-5xl mx-auto border border-top-gray">
        {/*containment div*/}
        <div className="flex justify-between">
          {/*Logo Container*/}
          <div className="cursor-pointer">
            <a href="/">
              <Image
                src="/../public/images/soulLogo.webp"
                alt="site logo"
                width={233}
                height={144}
              />
            </a>
          </div>

          {/*Link Container*/}

          <div className="hidden md:flex">
            <div
              onClick={() => setNavActive(!navActive)}
              className={`nav__menu-bar md:underline underline-offset-8 decoration-black `}
            ></div>
            <div
              className={`${
                navActive
                  ? 'active underline underline-offset-8 decoration-black'
                  : ''
              } nav__menu-list flex items-center space-x-8 text-gray-700 tracking-wider `}
            >
              {MENU_LIST.map((menu, idx) => (
                <div
                  onClick={() => {
                    setActiveIdx(idx);
                    setNavActive(false);
                  }}
                  key={menu.text}
                >
                  <NavItem active={activeIdx === idx} {...menu} />
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
          {/*Mobile Menu  button*/}
          <div className="flex relative flex-col gap-y-2 cursor-pointer pt-14 pr-3 md:hidden">
            <div className="w-24 h-1 bg-black shadow-gray-700 rounded"></div>
            <div className="w-24 h-1 bg-black shadow-gray-700 rounded"></div>
            <div className="w-24 h-1 bg-black shadow-gray-700 rounded"></div>
          </div>

          {/*Mobile Menu*/}
          <
        </div>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we used the same code and I ran into the same problem.

I fixed it with with using *next/router* and comparing the paths inside the NavItem.js component.

navitem.js

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

const NavItem = ({ href, text  }) => {

  const router = useRouter();
  const currentRoute = router.pathname;

  return (

    <Link href={href} className={currentRoute === `${href}` ? 'active' : ''}> {text} </Link>

  );

  
};

export default NavItem;
```

navbar.js

```
{PRIMARY_NAVIGATION_LIST.map((menu) => (
    
    <div key={menu.text} >   
        <NavItem 
            href={menu.href}
            text={menu.text}  
        />
    </div>
))}
```